# How to get a table creation script in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am rolling back to MySQL GUI Tools' MySQL Query Browser since I can't find the shortcut to get a table's creation script in MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

I cannot find such an option either, at least in the Community edition.

I suppose this corresponds to the **[Reverse Engineering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineering.html)** feature, which, unfortunately, is only available in the commercial edition *(quoting)* :

> reverse engineering a database
>   directly from a MySQL server **applies
>   to commercial versions of MySQL
>   Workbench only**.

Still, you can use plain-SQL to get the `create table` instruction that will allow you to create a table.

For instance, the following query :

```
show create table url_alias;
```

when executed on a drupal database, would give, when using right `click > copy field content` on the result :

```
'CREATE TABLE `url_alias` (
  `pid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `src` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '''',
  `dst` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '''',
  `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL default '''',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`pid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `dst_language` (`dst`,`language`),
  KEY `src_language` (`src`,`language`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Unfortunately *(again)*, MySQL Workbench adds some quotes everywhere when copying this way :-(

---

### EDIT: Using MySQL 8.0, there is an option to right `click > copy field (unquoted)` on the result to get the desired result without quotes.

In the end, the *simplest* solution, except from staying with MySQL Query Browser, will most likely be to connect to the database, using the command-line client, and execute the `show create table` query from there :

```
mysql> show create table url_alias\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: url_alias
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `url_alias` (
  `pid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `src` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `dst` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`pid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `dst_language` (`dst`,`language`),
  KEY `src_language` (`src`,`language`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Getting "*the right portion*" of the output is easier, there : no quote to remove.

---

And, just for the sake of completness, you could also use `mysqldump` to get your table's structure :

```
mysqldump --no-data --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --host=HOST DATABASE_NAME TABLE_NAME
```

Using the `--no-data` switch, you'll only get the structure *-- in the middle of some mode settings and all that*.

Comment: I seem to be able to use reverse engineering using the GA version v5.2.25.. CTRL+R

Comment: My 5.2.17 version of MySQL Workbench can do the unquoted copypasting after executing the 'show create table xxxx' query.

Comment: This is old. Right-click on a table and select "Copy to Clipboard" => "Create Statement". Alternatively, use "Server" => "Data Export" to export one or more schemas with or without data. Also, "Reverse Engineering" is available in the Community edition of Workbench.

Comment: For unquoted copypasting, Right click on result set and Copy Field (Unquoted).

Comment: There is now an easier way to do this, right click on your table and click "Copy SQL to clipboard". (Available in Community Edition)

Answer (score 57):

To get an individual table's creation script just right click on the table name and click Copy to Clipboard > Create Statement.

To enable the File > Forward Engineering SQL_CREATE Script.. option and to get the creation script for your entire database  :

1. Database > Reverse Engineer (Ctrl+R)
2. Go through the steps to create the EER Diagram
3. When viewing the EER Diagram click File > Forward Engineering SQL_CREATE Script... (Ctrl+Shift+G)

Comment: This worked for me, but on the version I am using (6.0 community), you click Database->Forward Engineer (not File->Forward Engineering).

Comment: Spent a time on mysqldump option to dump schema of a remote db, this helped me in the end.

Answer (score 30):

Right-click on the relevant table and choose either of:

- Copy to Clipboard > Create Statement
- Send to SQL Editor > Create Statement

That seems to work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use:

```
show create table <table_name>
```

Answer (score 6):

It is located in server administration rather than in SQL development.

- From the home screen select the database server instance your database is located on from the server administration section on the far right.
- From the menu on the right select **Data Export**.
- Select the database you want to export and choose a location.
- Click start export.

Comment: This worked much more simpler than the other options for me (although my option for Data Export was on the left side)

Answer (score 5):

I came here looking for the answer to the same question. But I found a much better answer myself.

`In the tables list, if you right-click on the table name there is a suite of CRUD script generation options in "Send to SQL Editor". You can select multiple tables and take the same approach too.`

My version of MySQL Workbench: 5.2.37

Comment: This is the best answer, just found this myself and was about to post it as an answer. To clarify, if you want a creation script, right click on the table, hover "Send to SQL editor," then click "Create Statement." It'll open up a new script window with the create statement. Much more convenient than any other answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I fully understood your problem, but if it's just about creating export scripts, you should forward engineer to SQL script - Ctrl + Shift + G or File -> Export -> first option.

Comment: This option is always disabled for me

Comment: yeah i have this problem too... anyone know how to enable this option?

Answer (score 3):

1 use command

```
show create table test.location
```

[image]

2. right click on selected row  and choose **Open Value In Viewer**
3. select tab **Text**
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Solution for MySQL Workbench 6.3E

- On left panel, right click your table and selecct "Table Inspector"
- On center panel, click DDL label

Answer (score 1):

In "model overview" or "diagram" just right-click on the table and you have the folowing options: "Copy Insert to clipboard" OR "Copy SQL to clipboard"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still an issue, but for me in 5.2.35CE it's possible to get the create scripts by:

1. Database --> Reverse Engineer
2. Under stored connection, choose your database
3. Hit "Next" a few times, choose which schema you want to reverse engineer, and let the tool work
4. You'll get an "EER Diagram" view with all the DB's schema.  If you right click on the table you care about and choose "Copy SQL to Clipboard" I think you'll have what you need.

Hopefully this helps someone else that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open MySQL Workbench (6.3 CE)
2. In "Navigator" select "Management"
3. Then select "Data Export" (Here select the table whose create script you wish to export)
4. In Drop down select "Dump Structure and Data"
5. Select checkbox "Include Create Schema"
6. Click the button "Start Export"
   Once export is complete it will display the location in which exported file is dumped in your system. Go to the location and open the exported file to find table creation script.

Or Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html

Answer (score 0):

U can use [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/) and its [scripting system](https://github.com/patrickallaert/MySQL-Proxy-scripts-for-devs/blob/master/debug.lua) to view SQL queries in realtime in the terminal.