# Exporting only table structure using mysqlworkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Can anybody tell whether it possible for exporting only the table structure using MySQL workbench

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a table creation script in MySQL Workbench?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433133/how-to-get-a-table-creation-script-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: could you tell me how to do it..

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**To get an individual table's creation script:**

- just right click on the table name and click Copy to Clipboard >
  Create Statement.

**To enable the File:**

- Forward Engineering SQL_CREATE Script.. option and to get the creation script for your entire database:

  1. Database > Reverse Engineer (Ctrl+R)
  2. Go through the steps to create the EER Diagram
  3. When viewing the EER Diagram click File > Forward Engineering SQL_CREATE Script... (Ctrl+Shift+G)

Answer (score 35):

For those of you that like the visual answer :

[image]

[image]

Start export - done :)

Comment: Oh Man! Awesome : )

Comment: Well that was easy!

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to do this at once too. Select "Data Export" in the navigator and then select the schema and the required tables. Then check the checkbox saying "Skip table data(no data)" and then click on "Start Export" button.

Comment: This option is now in the dropdown menu directly onder the column select window. You can choose "Dump structure only", "Dump data only" and "Dump structure and data".

Comment: This will not work if the user does not have permission to lock tables however

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL workbench ,when we are exporting data you have a 3 options 
Dump Data only,"**Dump Structure only**", Dump Data Structure only.

*Server -> Data Export -> select the schema , Dump Structure only (beside refresh)*

- export to self- contained file - location of SQL to export
  *click on start Export

$ when we are import this .SQL file , we will get schema without data only tables

Answer (score 3):

In `Workbench` version `6.3` is `Menu Server->Data Export` and then select `"Dump structure only"` in the selection list at the right of the window

Answer (score 2):

1) Right click the table and select "Table Inspector"
2) Last tab "DDL" has the table scheme

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Open MySql Workbench

Step 2: Go to Server >> Data Export

Step 3: Select Your table or database and select one of option from

```
    1. Dump Structure and data (default selected option) , or 

    2. Dump data only , or

    3. Dump Structure only
```

Step 4: Click on 'Start Export'

```
    NOTE:if system is Ubuntu Linux then you will your exported files at here 'HOME/dumps'
```