# Any way to retrieve ddl for a table using select statement (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, ddl

I have a mysql database. I want to pull the SQL that will create the table. Like the mysqldump command, where it outputs something like

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_user` (
  login_name TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
  login_password TEXT(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  can_edit int DEFAULT 0,
  can_add int DEFAULT 0,
  can_delete int(1) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (login_name));
```

if you run it on a table called `admin_user`. However, I want to do this using purely SQL, preferably a select statement. I saw something about `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, is there any way I could do an inner join or something to a select statement, or would I have to do it a different way? Is this even possible using purely SQL, or do you need to use `mysqldump`?

Comment: You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433133/how-to-get-a-table-creation-script-in-mysql-workbench)... might help

Comment: What's wrong with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: You may create SQL query which will reconstruct table's CREATE TABLE statement, of course, but it will be too complex. You cannot use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output as rowsource in a query, but you may save it (using exporting possibilities of your client) to file.